# contour intrgration, what's the right answer?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

There exists an integral as follow:
$$
\bar G(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dE}{2\pi\hbar}e^{-iEt/\hbar}\frac{1}{E-\epsilon+i0^{+}}
$$
My solution is:
$$
{2\pi\hbar}\bar G(t)=-i\pi e^{-i\epsilon t/\hbar} + P.V.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dE\frac{e^{-iEt/\hbar}}{E-\epsilon}\\=-i\pi e^{-i\epsilon t/\hbar} + 2\pi i \frac{1}{2} Res\Big(\frac{e^{-iEt/\hbar}}{E-\epsilon},\epsilon\Big)=-i\pi e^{-i\epsilon t/\hbar} + i\pi e^{-i\epsilon t/\hbar}=0
$$
where I have used Principle Value formla(a.k.a. Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem). What's wrong? someone say the answer is $\frac{-i}{\hbar}\theta(t)e^{-i0^{+}t}\exp(-i\epsilon t/\hbar)$.

Comment: Note that the answers agree for $t<0$. You need to be quite careful about what sign of $t$ is being assumed, since the principal-value integration rests on being able to complete the integral over the real line in either the upper or lower half plane.

Comment: I suspect that the argument of the exponential is $-i E t/\hbar$.

Comment: @RonGordon: Tks, you're right. I've updated it.